# WSO2 Identity Server can't see users in Management Console

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have added secondary user stores and would like to see the users from these stores in the management console but they are not showing up. I can log in with these users via the implicit flow, so I know they are being added correctly but only the primary store users are showing up in the "Home > Users" section. I have selected the domain "ALL USER STORE DOMAINS" or even the specific secondary user stores from that list. Secondary store users are not appearing either way. Furthermore, the roles that are specific to those secondary user stores show up in the "Home > Roles" section, but when I select "View Users" on a role there, it says "No users are found". Why is this? My secondary user stores are set up as Read-Only. My WSO2 Identity Server Version is 5.7.0.

Comment: What is your userstore?

Comment: my userstore is LDAP

Answer (score 0):

If your user store is an LDAP, make sure the `UserSearchBase` is set correctly.